# Prevent msdeploy from syncing unchanged files after TFS Build?

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, msdeploy, webdeploy

When doing a get-latest from TFS, all timestamps are set to the time at which the get operation was executed. When doing running msdeploy to perform a sync, the timestamps in the source are compared with the timestamps on the target server. Of course, this means that with TFS + msdeploy, every file will be pushed to the target servers after every build, unless

- You use incremental builds
- You have only a single build agent in the build controller's pool.

If the build definition is set to do Clean builds, or if you want to utilize multiple build agents, then this no longer works.

This topic comes up all the time, and once every couple of years I cast out new lines in case something has changed. This could be fixed in a couple of different ways:

- TFS sets timestamps on workspace files to the last checkin time.
- TFS sets timestamps on workspace files to the last modified time from the files themselves when they were last checked in.
- msdeploy uses some content-based comparison method (e.g. MD5) to compare files, rather than timestamp comparisons.
- Something else?

I never know where to go to search for this stuff since both of these teams are pretty opaque--the webdeploy team in particular. Is this a problem that has been solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

The TFS and visual Studio teams are entirely transparent and you can submit feature requests through http://visualstudio.uservoice.com and bugs through http://connect.microsoft.com.

However all files within a server workspace are set to the date the file was last modified on the server. Local workspaces physically compare the file contents to determin changes. You can change from local workspace to server workspace in the workspace properties.

Comment: MrHinsh! I love your blog. Our Team Project Collection is configured to default to Server workspaces, so I would assume that the build agent is creating one of those; however, I'll need to dig into the build process template to be sure. However, even if this is the case, then my assumptions about the underlying cause must be incorrect because our msdeploy syncs are still pushing every file to the target server.

Comment: I've reviewed our build process template and the MSDN documentation, and it appears as though the CreateWorkspace build activity doesn't allow for specification of a FileTime parameter. However, since the workspaces are created with each build, we can't simply change the properties on existing workspaces since they won't be around for very long. Do you know how to create the workspaces using CheckIn FileTime mode?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we got around this by writing a powershell script to wrap the `.cmd` file produced by the Web Publishing Pipeline, and passing the `-useChecksum` flag in the command that invokes the `.cmd` script. Since the boilerplate `.cmd` created by WPP allows for passing additional arguments to msdeploy, we were able to accomplish this with a line like the following.

`& "MyProject.cmd" /u:agent /p:P@ssw0rd /m:$ComputerName /y -useChecksum`

In this way, even though TFS is creating workspaces with timestamps set to the get-latest time, msdeploy is now instructed to use checksums instead.